# Probability question of independent random varaibles

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution

Let 
$X\sim \mathcal{N}(6,1)$ and $Y\sim\mathcal{N}(7,1)$ be two independent normal variables. Find $Pr(X>Y)$.
the answer is $0.2389$ but I do not know how to do it.

Comment: Find $X-Y$ which is itself a random variable , there is formula for combi.ning two random normal variable

Answer (score 0):

Hint: what is the distribution of $Y-X$ ?
(1,1)